# Start Rails server from within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Is it possible to start a rails server from within a running rails server?

I would also like to install the gems using 'bundle install'.
I made a simple setup, but when i invoke 'bundle install', the gems from the running rails server are installed and not the gems for the server i wish to start.

What would be the best strategy to launch another rails server.

Comment: I know that's an annoying question but... what do you want to achieve exactly? You can, of course, always fork a new process and then `exec` the command (in your case the new rails server) but frankly I'm having a hard time to think of a reasonable usecase. Can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @paukul Maybe he's buidling a Rails app which will manage other Rails servers? ;) Anyway, some little voice in my head yells that's _extremely_ dangerous to use `exec` just like that, especially for spawning whole servers.

Comment: @naliwajek of course, maybe I should have made myself clear that I don't consider this a good idea ;)

Comment: Just as naliwajek mentioned, i have a server that manages other servers.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated in the comments, you can spawn shell commands from your Rails application. You have several options. http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/

If you want to inherit the user environment when running bundle commands, you might want to spawn a bash login shell then run the command. E.g. ```/bin/bash -l -c "command here".

Although you didn't ask about killing them, if you're only going to run this and you're not building anything to keep track of process IDs, you could find and kill other instances with some `ps aux | awk '/process name or unique path/ {print $2}' | xargs kill` magic